# Ionic 2 lazy loading components

Tags: ionic2

My app is really big and has like 30 components and pages, I load all of them in my app.module.ts and sometimes the application turn slow. I wonder if it has anything to do it.

**My question:** What's the correct way to lazy load components and use angular 2 features (more modules) with Ionic 2?

Comment: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/8102 They are STILL working on it.

Comment: Have a look at http://blog.ionic.io/ionic-and-lazy-loading-pt-1/ for Ionic 3 (lazy loading added)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Ionic 3, you can lazy load components.

Simply, create a new module for each component/page.

Here's an example of how a module of the HomePage should look like:

```
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [MyApp, HomePage],
  imports: [ ... ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [MyApp, HomePage],
  providers: [ ... ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

After creating the module, attach `@IonicPage()` to the component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';
@IonicPage()
@Component(... )
export class HomePage { ... }
```

Now you can use your page/component as a string without using the `import` statement:

```
rootPage:any = 'HomePage';
```

for more descriptibe answer, check out this [Ionic Lazy Loading blog post](http://blog.ionic.io/ionic-and-lazy-loading-pt-1/).